# Spark-submit ClassNotFound exception

Tags: scala, jar, classpath, apache-spark

I'm having problems with a "ClassNotFound" Exception using this simple example:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import java.net.URLClassLoader

import scala.util.Marshal

class ClassToRoundTrip(val id: Int) extends scala.Serializable {
}

object RoundTripTester {

  def test(id : Int) : ClassToRoundTrip = {

    // Get the current classpath and output. Can we see simpleapp jar?
    val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    val urls = cl.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs
    urls.foreach(url => println("Executor classpath is:" + url.getFile))

    // Simply instantiating an instance of object and using it works fine.
    val testObj = new ClassToRoundTrip(id)
    println("testObj.id: " + testObj.id)

    val testObjBytes = Marshal.dump(testObj)
    val testObjRoundTrip = Marshal.load[ClassToRoundTrip](testObjBytes)  // <<-- ClassNotFoundException here
    testObjRoundTrip
  }
}

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    val urls = cl.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs
    urls.foreach(url => println("Driver classpath is: " + url.getFile))

    val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    distData.foreach(x=> RoundTripTester.test(x))
  }
}
```

In local mode, submitting as per the docs generates a "ClassNotFound" exception on line 31, where the ClassToRoundTrip object is deserialized. Strangely, the earlier use on line 28 is okay:

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" \
             --master local[4] \
             target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

However, if I add extra parameters for "driver-class-path", and "-jars", it works fine, on local.

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" \
             --master local[4] \
             --driver-class-path /home/xxxxxxx/workspace/SimpleApp/target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar \
             --jars /home/xxxxxxx/workspace/SimpleApp/target/scala-2.10/SimpleApp.jar \
             target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

However, submitting to a local dev master, still generates the same issue:

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" \
             --master spark://localhost.localdomain:7077 \
             --driver-class-path /home/xxxxxxx/workspace/SimpleApp/target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar \
             --jars /home/xxxxxxx/workspace/SimpleApp/target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar \
             target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

I can see from the output that the JAR file is being fetched by the executor.

Logs for one of the executor's are here:

stdout: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DQvvGhKm

stderr: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MPZZVa0Q

I'm using Spark 1.0.2. The ClassToRoundTrip is included in the JAR. 
I would rather not have to hardcode values in SPARK_CLASSPATH or SparkContext.addJar. Can anyone help?

Comment: Update - I've been able to work around this by setting the "spark.executor.extraClassPath" and making the JAR file locally available on each of the executor's at the path. I don't understand why this is needed: The JAR is being fetched from Spark's internal HTTP server by the executor's and copied into the working directory of each executor.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue today. Jar is being fetched by executor and it has the class its looking for even though it throws ClassNotFoundException!! I am on 1.0.2 btw

Comment: Update again - I think this might have something to do with serialization. We found a couple of days ago that changing the serialization method made the problem go away. I'm still not sure why, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this same issue. If master is local then program runs fine for most people. If they set it to (also happened to me) "spark://myurl:7077" it doesn't work. Most people get error because an anonymous class was not found during execution. It is resolved by using SparkContext.addJars ("Path to jar").

**Make sure you are doing the following things: -**

- SparkContext.addJars("*Path to jar created from maven [hint: mvn package]*").
- I have used SparkConf.setMaster("*spark://myurl:7077*") in code and have supplied same as argument while submitting job to spark via command line.
- When you specify class in command line, make sure your are writing it's complete name with URL. eg: *"packageName.ClassName"*
- Final command should look like this
  bin/spark-submit --class *"packageName.ClassName"* --master *spark://myurl:7077* *pathToYourJar/target/yourJarFromMaven.jar*

**Note:** this jar pathToYourJar/target/yourJarFromMaven.jar in last point is also set in code as in first point of this answer.

Comment: This link is invaluable - http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting ; Note that you need to include a 'fat' jar if you do not plan to copy the dependencies to all the nodes. Kindly check here to see how to build one using sbt:assembly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea

Answer (score 4):

I also had same issue. I think --jars is not shipping the jars to executors.
After I added this into SparkConf, it works fine.

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("...").setJars(Seq("/a/b/x.jar", "/c/d/y.jar"))
```

[This web page for trouble shooting](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting) is useful too.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the SPARK_CLASS_PATH in **spark-env.sh** file like this：

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=your local ip 
SPARK_CLASSPATH=your external jars
```

and you should submit with spark shell like this：`spark-submit --class your.runclass --master spark://yourSparkMasterHostname:7077 /your.jar`

and your java code like this:

```
SparkConf sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkOnHbase");  JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkconf);
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven and [Maven Assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) plugin to build your jar file with `mvn package`, ensure that the assembly plugin is configured correctly to point to your Spark app's main class.

Something like this should be added to your `pom.xml` to avoid any `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`'s:

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.my.package.SparkDriverApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I figured out was if you have build your project without any warnings then you don't have to write extra code for master and other things. Although it is a good practice but you can just avoid it. Like here in my case there was no warnings in the project so I was able to run it without any extra code. 
[Project Structure Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lDGG.jpg)

In the case where I have some build related warnings there I have to take care of JAR paths, my URL and the master in code as well as while executing it.

I hope it may help someone. Cheers !