# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running Spark Application

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception, apache-phoenix

I am new to Spark (Scala) and I am trying to run one spark application through spark submit. Unfortunately I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.

Here is my spark submit command:

```
./spark-submit --class "spark.phoenix.a" --master local --deploy-mode client /home/ec2-user/phoenix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is my Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.phoenix.a
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Here is my sample code:

```
package spark.phoenix
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object a {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import org.apache.phoenix.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

    val zkQuorum = "localhost:2181"
    val master = "local[*]"
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    sparkConf.setAppName("phoenix-spark-save")
        .setMaster(s"${master}")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    // read from orders phoenix table
    val df = sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame("TABLE1",
        Seq.apply("ID", "COL1"),
        zkUrl = Some.apply(s"${zkQuorum}") )


  }
}
```

Comment: could you verify that your jar file indeed has spark.phoenix.a class inside?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark-submit ClassNotFound exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688349/spark-submit-classnotfound-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with your pom.xml file(if you are using maven). You haven't added **maven-shade-plugin**.

Add below properties to your pom.xml and and try once.

```
         <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>eclipse-add-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>doc-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                    <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                        <arg>-feature</arg>
                    </args>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms1024m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=${CodeCacheSize}</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                    <javacArgs>
                        <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>-Xlint:all,-serial,-path</javacArg>
                    </javacArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.xerial.snappy</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang.modules</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score -1):

please remove the `""` from your command.

Try something like this.

```
./spark-submit --class spark.phoenix.a --master local --deploy-mode client /home/ec2-user/phoenix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```