# How to spark-submit with main class in jar?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

There are a ton of questions about `ClassNotFoundException` but I haven't seen any (yet) that fit this specific case. I am attempting to run the following command:

`spark-submit --master local[*] --class com.stronghold.HelloWorld scala-ts.jar`

It throws the following exception:

```
\u@\h:\w$ spark_submit --class com.stronghold.HelloWorld scala-ts.jar                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ⬡ 9.8.0 [±master ●●●] 
2018-05-06 19:52:33 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, asusTax resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.184 instead (on interface p1p1)                               
2018-05-06 19:52:33 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address                                                                                       
2018-05-06 19:52:33 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable                                
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stronghold.HelloWorld                               
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                     
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                          
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                          
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)                                        
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)                                        
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:235)                     
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:836)                                                                  
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)        
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)             
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)               
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)                    
2018-05-06 19:52:34 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called                   
2018-05-06 19:52:34 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e8a77988-d30c-4e96-81fe-bcaf5d565c75
```

However, the jar clearly contains this class:

```
1     " zip.vim version v28                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    1 " Browsing zipfile /home/[USER]/projects/scala_ts/out/artifacts/TimeSeriesFilter_jar/scala-ts.jar
    2 " Select a file with cursor and press ENTER
    3  
    4 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    5 com/
    6 com/stronghold/
    7 com/stronghold/HelloWorld$.class
    8 com/stronghold/TimeSeriesFilter$.class
    9 com/stronghold/DataSource.class
   10 com/stronghold/TimeSeriesFilter.class
   11 com/stronghold/HelloWorld.class
   12 com/stronghold/scratch.sc
   13 com/stronghold/HelloWorld$delayedInit$body.class
```

Typically, the hang up here is on file structure, but I am pretty sure that's correct here:

```
../
scala_ts/
| .git/
| .idea/
| out/
| | artifacts/
| | | TimeSeriesFilter_jar/
| | | | scala-ts.jar
| src/
| | main/
| | | scala/
| | | | com/
| | | | | stronghold/
| | | | | | DataSource.scala
| | | | | | HelloWorld.scala
| | | | | | TimeSeriesFilter.scala
| | | | | | scratch.sc
| | test/
| | | scala/
| | | | com/
| | | | | stronghold/
| | | | | | AppTest.scala
| | | | | | MySpec.scala                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
| target/
| README.md
| pom.xml
```

I have run other jobs with the same structure at work (so, a different environment).  I am now trying to gain some more facility with a home project, but this seems to be an early hang up.

In a nutshell, am I just missing something glaringly obvious?

**APPENDIX**

For those that are interested, here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stronghold</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-ts</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-tools.testing</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies for the lack of clarity.  I ran the command from within the same directory as the `.jar` (`/home/[USER]/projects/scala_ts/out/artifacts/TimeSeriesFilter_jar/`). That said, just to be clear, specifying the full path does not change the outcome.

It should also be noted that I can run HelloWorld from within Intellij, and it uses the same class reference (`com.stronghold.HelloWorld`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afraid none of these were the issue.  I had previously tried deleting everything in the project and starting over, but that didn't work either. Once it occurred to me start an entirely different project, it worked just fine.  Apparently Intellij (of which I am a fan) decided to create a hidden problem somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the path to the jar file so `spark-submit` (as any other command line tool) could find and use it?

Given the path `out/artifacts/TimeSeriesFilter_jar/scala-ts.jar` I'd use the following:

```
spark-submit --class com.stronghold.HelloWorld out/artifacts/TimeSeriesFilter_jar/scala-ts.jar
```

Please note that you should be in the project's main directory which seems to be `/home/[USER]/projects/scala_ts`.

Please also note that I removed `--master local[*]` since that's the default master URL `spark-submit` uses.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your *pom* file, *the jar file you are referencing doesn't match with what you have in the pom file* as

```
  <artifactId>scala-ts</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

The above two line in *pom* file suggests that your jar file should be `scala-ts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` but you have used `scala-ts.jar` only. So I am assuming you are referencing old jar.

Here are few steps you can apply

```
1. clean the project and package again
2. make sure the jar file name by going to target folder of the project
3. you can give the exact path to the target folder to point to the jar when you apply spark-submit command
```

Comment: I cleaned and packaged the jar again, but I am afraid it didn't make a difference.  As for referencing an old jar, I only created one for this project.  Just to be safe, I deleted the jar and started from scratch by building a new one.  Unfortunately, no dice.

Comment: did you check the jar file name in target folder of the project?

Comment: Sorry, I was swamped with work this week.  I am just getting back to this. The answer is yes, the jar name is correct.

Comment: what do you mean by correct? can you share the jar file name with the full path?

Comment: I mean there is no other jar.  The only one I have built is here: `../scala_ts/out/artifacts/TimeSeriesFilter_jar/scala-ts.jar`. Also, there are no jars in the target folder, they sit in the out folder when built.

Comment: I am talking about `../scala_ts/target/` . whats the jar name there? use that jar. thats what i meant in my answer

Comment: In general, in a variety of scala applications that have run (in my work environment), there is no information about jar name in the target folder.

Comment: I am looking at you pom file and your pom file suggests that when you package to make jar file it goes to target folder with name `scala-ts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` with all the updates. Thats why I suggest you to use that one and try

Comment: I hear you, but again, that file does not exist.  There is no jar called `scala-ts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.  There is only a jar called `scala-ts.jar`.  You cannot access a jar that does not exist: `Error: Unable to access jarfile scala-ts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. The issue isn't accessing the right jar, I think it has something to do with how the jar is built.

Comment: yeah I guess so too. are you building your jar using artifact or maven?

Comment: I am indeed.  I added an artifact to the project, and built the jar using that artifact configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170973/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-marvin-ward-jr).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **maven-shade** plugin and build > run.

Here is the reference, it may help you.

[Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running Spark Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815023/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-while-running-spark-application/50167760#50167760)

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why this is useful?  I didn't have to use uber-jars in other contexts.