# ClassNotFoundException in spark-sbumit for scala code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

When i export the program into a jar file and execute it i get an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error.

the code i'm using is below.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

**SBT**

```
name := "testFunctions"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "2.17.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "2.17.1"
)

initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  if (sys.props("java.specification.version") != "1.8")
    sys.error("Java 8 is required for this project.")
}
```

Scala Code

```
/**
  * Created by cloudera on 7/23/17.
  */

import better.files.File._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object func {


  val forDelete = (root/"/home/cloudera/Documents/fabo")
    .createIfNotExists()

  if (forDelete.exists)
    forDelete.delete()


  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("Get ForEx Data")
      .getOrCreate()



  }

}
```

**Command line executing jar file**

```
spark-submit --class func --master local[*] /home/cloudera/testFunctions/out/artifacts/testFunctions_jar
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: func
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

** **The Tree structure where the code live looks like below** ** -
so the class called func lives in the scala directory

```
\main
    \java
    \resources
    \scala
        -func(class)
    \scala-2.11
```

Output from **jar tf name_of_jar.jar**

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
func.class
func$.class
```

Comment: This post looks likes it's relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688349/spark-submit-classnotfound-exception

Comment: can we see the tree structure of where your func class is ?

Comment: Hey, could you run `jar tf your_output_file.jar` and check if the class is there?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I've updated the post to include the tree structure

Comment: when running jar tf name_of_jar.jar i get the following:  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
func.class
func$.class